# Как можно выровнять combobox'ы, которые находятся в 2-ух разных контейнерах?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как я могу сделать выравнивание по красной линии(т.е по ComboBox'ам, которые сверху):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что верхняя часть- это отдельный Grid (3 колонки), вложенный в главный Grid, а нижняя часть является GroupBox, которая вложена в главный Grid.

Теоретически я могу все это объединить в 1 Grid, но тогда из-за GroupBox все равно будет небольшое расхождение...

Разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows.DictionaryConfigurationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Конфигурация справочника" Height="680" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding DictConfigVM}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Тип базы данных</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DbKinds}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDbKind}"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Сервер (MSSQL) или путь к файлу (MS ACCESS)</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=FilePathOrServerName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название базы данных</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DbNameEnable}" Text="{Binding Path=DbName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название таблицы</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="350" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableDescriptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTableDescription}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Schema}" />
                                <Run Text="." />
                                <Run Text="{Binding TableName}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshTablesCommand}"  >
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIcon}"  Source="../Icons/Refresh.png"/>
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        Обновить
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="4">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Ключ таблицы (целое число)</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedKeyColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="5">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название поля для нормализованного значения</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedFullTextColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <GroupBox DataContext="{Binding AlgorithmConfigVM}">
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    Настройка алгоритма
                </GroupBox.Header>
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NormalizeServices}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNormalizeService}" DisplayMemberPath="NormalizeAlgorithmType.Name"/>
                        <Border>
                            <StackPanel >
                                <Label>Параметры алгоритма</Label>
                                <ListView MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Item.Name}"></Label>
                                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBox>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label>Настройка привязок результатов раскладки</Label>
                                <ListView Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldBindings}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBinding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Cursor="Arrow" >
                                                        <TextBox.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})" Mode="OneWay">
                                                                <Binding Path="Item.Name" />
                                                                <Binding Path="Item.Description" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBox.Text>
                                                    </TextBox>
                                                </Label>
                                                <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},
                                        Path=DataContext.AvailableColumns}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding Value}">
                                                </ComboBox>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </GroupBox>
        </Border>


        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" Margin="0 0 25 0">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIconWithMargin}"  Source="../Icons/Save.png"/>
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Сохранить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}" Margin="0 0 25 0">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIconWithMargin}"  Source="../Icons/Cancel.png"/>
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Отменить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что с чем нужно выровнять. Можно примерную разметку?

Comment: Скорее всего вам понадобится SharedSizeGroup

Comment: @VladD добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся `SharedSizeGroup`, чтобы «перенести» вниз неизвестную ширину кнопки. Для этого внешний `Grid` объявим как `SharedSizeScope`. Получится что-то такое:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!-- ColumnDefinitions тут не нужно -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding DictConfigVM}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ButtonWidth"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <!-- и так далее -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Тип базы данных</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DbKinds}" .../>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Сервер (MSSQL) или...</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FilePathOrServerName,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Border>

            <!-- тут кнопка в отдельной колонке -->
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshTablesCommand}"
                        Tooltip="Обновить">
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIcon}" Source="../Icons/Refresh.png"/>
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Ключ таблицы (целое число)</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" .../>
            </Border>
            <!-- и так далее -->
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <!-- положим пустую колонку такого же размера как и сверху -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ButtonWidth"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- ВАЖНО! для компенсации лишних двух Border-ов отступим назад на 10 px -->
            <Border Margin="0,0,-10,0">
                <GroupBox DataContext="{Binding AlgorithmConfigVM}" Header="Настройка алгоритма">
                    <Border>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NormalizeServices}" .../>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel >
                                    <Label>Параметры алгоритма</Label>
                                    <ListView MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                           ...
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </GroupBox>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 0">
            ...
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```